# Exception handling-Whitelabel Error Page containing the HTTP status code and an error message if no mappings for the /error endpoint are found

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, exception

I have a rest service where it is connecting to mongdb to get the response.Ater the spring boot upgrade the error response was not appearing in Browser. It is displaying like below. Not sure why it is giving null vales in the error response. If I try some other way , it is giving proper response only in Postmand not in Browser .

Can any one help me how to format the Error response properly in Browser.Thanks in Advance

**Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Mar 25 22:57:12 UTC 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
Resource Not Found**

Below is the syntax of code:

```
   import java.util.Date;
    
    public class ErrorMessage {
    
        private int statusCode;
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
        private Date timestamp;
    
        private String message;
        private String path;
        private String error;
    
        public ErrorMessage(int value, Date date, String message, String resourceNotFound) {
        }
    
        public ErrorMessage(String status, String message, String stackTrace) {
        }
    
        public int getStatusCode() {
            return statusCode;
        }
    
        public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
            this.statusCode = statusCode;
        }
    
        public Date getTimestamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }
    
        public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }
    
        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
    
        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    
       
    
        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }
    
        public void setPath(String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }
    
        public String getError() {
            return error;
        }
    
        public void setError(String error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
    
    CustomExceptionClass:
    
    public class CustomDataNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
        public CustomDataNotFoundException() {
            super();
        }
    
        public CustomDataNotFoundException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
    
    Exception Handler :
    
    
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class ValidationExceptionHandler
             {
    
    
    
        @ExceptionHandler(CustomDataNotFoundException.class)
        public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleCustomDataNotFoundExceptions(
                Exception e
        ) {
            HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND; // 404
    
            // converting the stack trace to String
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
            e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
            String stackTrace = stringWriter.toString();
    
            return new ResponseEntity<>(
                    new ErrorMessage(
                            "404",
                            e.getMessage(),
                            stackTrace
                    ),
                    status
            );
        }
    
    }
```

Browser:

```
{     "statusCode": 0,
        "timestamp": null,
        "message": null,
        "path": null,
        "error": null
    }
```

**Postman:**

```
  {     "statusCode": 0,
        "timestamp": null,
        "message": null,
        "path": null,
        "error": null
    }
```

Controller :

```
 if (system!= null && !system.isEmpty())
            documentMap.put("ClaimId", claimId);
 List<? extends Bson> pipelines = getAggregate(queryLimit, projectFields, documentMap);
      
        List database= collectionDB.aggregate(pipelines).into(Aggregate);
        if (system.isEmpty() && !system.isEmpty()) {
            documentMap.remove("system.value");
            List<? extends Bson> pipelines= getAggregate(queryLimit, projectFields, documentMap);
            
            List database2= collectionDB.aggregate(pipelines2).into(Aggregate2);
            if (!system.isEmpty())
                throw new ValidationException(RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        if (system.isEmpty())
            throw new CustomDataNotFoundException(RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND);
```

Comment: Can anyone help me on the above issue, not able to figure out what is the issue?